# What is the difference between :key and v-bind:key when constructing a v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

There are examples in the Vue docs using the key keyword use both `:key=` and `v-bind:key=` when defining the key in a `v-for` loop. Is one just syntactic sugar of the other, or do they do different things?

[Examples from the docs using both types:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component)

**`:key`**

```
<my-component v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"></my-component>
```

**`v-bind:key`**

```
<my-component
  v-for="(item, index) in items"
  v-bind:item="item"
  v-bind:index="index"
  v-bind:key="item.id"
></my-component>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`:key=` and `v-bind:key=` are exactly the same.

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

> **v-bind**
>
> Shorthand: `:`

Comment: same as @click and v-on:click